# How to print used SQL query when using PreparedStatement (JDBC)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I used PreparedStatement in my Java program. I need to debug the SQL query because it's not working fine.

Is there is away to print the used SQL statement with the values inserted

for example in PreparedStatement:

select * from table where a=?

and than I set the ?

could I print the used SQL, for example:

select * from table where a=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2683214/839527 previous question will help you.

Comment: there's a good discussion of this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382532/how-can-i-get-the-sql-of-a-preparedstatement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be done with `java.sql.PreparedStatement` interface itself; it depends on the implementation by your database vendor.

But you're in luck; the MySQL driver allows you to do it using its `toString` implementation:

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-display-a-prepared-statement-with-bind-variables-using-mysql.html

You need to be aware that using this vendor-specific feature binds your code to MySQL.  You can't change databases without changing your code.

Comment: Thanks ... it's OK i'm just going to use it for debug purpose only.