# How can I print the statement from PreparedStatementWrapper object?

Tags: java, sql, string

I created a `PreparedStatementWrapper` object containing an `INSERT` statement. Now I would like to print my object. I want to test my `INSERT` statement, to see that it is correct. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683214/get-query-from-java-sql-preparedstatement

Answer (score 0):

Just use `System.out.println()` and `toString()` method before you execute it.

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(QUERY);
ps.setString(1, "Test");
System.out.println(ps.toString());
```

---

EDIT: It works only if you are using `MYSQL` driver.

Comment: yes, you right it works only with MySQL driver. So it's not defined in JDBC.

Comment: Works for PostgreSQL as well. Wether or not it works depends on how the JDBC driver's implementation of the Statement interface implements the `toString()` method.