# print complete query of PreparedStatement with loggers

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

How to print complete query of **PreparedStatement** with loggers?

Using **JDBC** Driver as: **com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver**

```
log4.properties contains
log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=logs/ProductDataLibrary.log
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxFileSize=10240KB
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxBackupIndex=0
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{DATE}~ %5p ~ %C:%L ~ %x ~ %m%n
```

I have tried with `preparedstatement.toString()` method, but it is printing some @object not the complete **SQL** query ?

Comment: Why is your question tagged mysql, when you talk about the SQL Server driver?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382532/how-can-i-get-the-sql-of-a-preparedstatement

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get query from java.sql.PreparedStatement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683214/get-query-from-java-sql-preparedstatement)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an abstraction layer (such as hibernate) you are probably best to use their built in logging.

If you want to roll your own, you should wrap the `java.sql.Connection` using the delegate pattern. Eg:

```
public class WrappedConnection implements Connection {
    private Connection delegate;
    public WrappedConnection(Connection delegate) { this.delegate = delegate; }
    public PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String sql) {
       PreparedStatement ps = delegate.prepareStatement(sql);
       return new WrappedPreparedStatement(sql, ps);
    }
    // delegate all Connection methods to the delegate
}

public class WrappedPreparedStatement implements PreparedStatement {
    private String sql;
    private PreparedStatement delegate;
    public WrappedPreparedStatement(String sql, PreparedStatement delegate) { 
       this.sql = sql; 
       this.delegate = delegate;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return sql;
    }
    public ResultSet executeQuery() throws SQLException {
        // perhaps you might want to do some logging here?
        return delegate.executeQuery();
    }
    // delegate all PreparedStatement methods to the delegate
}
```

Using this approach, you'll likely wrap `Connection.createStatement(*)` and `Connection.prepareCall(*)` too.

***edit***

It looks like someone's already done the hard work for you, take a look at [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/)

Answer (score -2):

Add DEBUG or TRACE level to java.sql.PreparedStatement in log4j.properties

```
log4j.logger.java.sql.PreparedStatement=DEBUG
```

or

```
log4j.logger.java.sql.PreparedStatement=TRACE
```

If you want to get a complete JDBC operations logging add DEBUG level to java.sql

```
log4j.logger.java.sql=DEBUG
```

or if you want a concrete logging for individual JDBC class add

```
log4j.logger.java.sql.theclass=DEBUG
```

an example

```
log4j.logger.java.sql.Connection=DEBUG    
log4j.logger.java.sql.Statement=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.PreparedStatement=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.ResultSet=DEBUG
```

**edit**: My mistake, I forgot SQLServer JDBC driver does not use log4j

You cant configure logging via java.util.logging.LogManager with a properties file

```
handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler


    # Default global logging level.
    .level= ALL

    # default file output
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = /tmp/sql.log
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 5000000
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 20
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = ALL

    # Facility specific properties.
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.level=ALL
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Statement.level=ALL
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.level=ALL
```

And get it at runtime

```
LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(new FileInputStream("c:/tmp/sql.properties"));
```

More info

[Tracing Driver Operation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms378517.aspx)