# Get the SQL from a java.sql.Connection

Tags: java, jdbc, connection

I have a thread which iterates a pool of occupied connections and verifies if each `Connection` has reached the maximum time allowed for being at this pool.

If the `Connection` reaches that time, I perform a rollback, close the `Connection` and log a message containing information about the `Connection`.

I would like to add the SQL command performed by that `Connection` to the logged message.
Is there a way of getting the SQL, or the `PreparedStatement`, from a `java.sql.Connection`?

I've wondered to extend `java.sql.Connection` and inject that information to the object before execute the command. So that, I would be able to get it when necessary.
Do you know a more elegant way of doing that?

**EDIT**
It isn't duplicate. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683214/get-query-from-java-sql-preparedstatement) is about `PreparedStatement` and I don't have it. I only have a `java.sql.Connection`

Answer (score 2):

Just print it with the standard way `System.out.println(preparedStatement);` .

In case it doesn't work, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2683339/2486904).

Comment: I don't have the PreparedStatement. That's what I'm asking for.