# Why this JDBC statement causes an exception?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have linked JDBC with PostgreSQL. How do we create a view with a placeholder?

But I get this error:

> SQL Exception.: ERROR: there is no parameter $1 Position: 72

```
queryString = "CREATE VIEW clients AS (SELECT client_id FROM Client WHERE firstname = ?)";
pStatement = conn.prepareStatement( queryString );

System.out.println("Enter the name of a client");
br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in) );
String client_name = br.readLine();

pStatement.setString(1, client_name);
pStatement.executeUpdate();
```

The last line (`pStatement.executeUpdate();`) causes an exception. Why?

Comment: Not sure that a placeholder will be correctly taken into account, inside creation queries . Look at this topic and attempt to print the final query to have some hint of what will the statement really look like after your setString . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683214/get-query-from-java-sql-preparedstatement

Comment: You can't create a view with a parameter (btw: the parentheses around the select for a `create view` are totally useless)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a view called `"clients"` which filters for a subset of clients does not seem desirable - are you sure you don't just want a prepared statement, instead of a view?

If you do want to create views dynamically, you'll need to construct the SQL in Java (DDL statements cannot be parameterized):

```
String queryString = "CREATE VIEW \"clients_named_%1$s\" AS (SELECT client_id FROM client WHERE firstname = '%1$s')";

System.out.println("Enter the name of a client");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String clientName = br.readLine();

// sanitize in a way that makes sense for your data
clientName = clientName.replaceAll("\\W", "");

Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(String.format(queryString, clientName));
```

Needless to say, sanitizing user input is important in this case.